# Retrieve Failed Fieldnames and Messages with Laravel Validator

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'd like to use Laravel's built in validator facade to validate some form fields and then pass back the failed field names using the with operator ex:

```
foreach(Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules)->getErrors() as $field => $message)
{
  $failed_fields[$field] = $message;
}



return Redirect::to('user/login')->with('errors', array($failed_fields);
```

so I can then pass the array to a js array and consume the errors to then find the fields and change their background colors etc.

Any idea how to access these values in this or a similar manner?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out after looking at the classes responsible and it was quite simple for me.

```
 if($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::route('cart')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->with('json_field_errors',json_encode($validator->errors()->getMessages()))
                ->withInput(Input::except('card_number'));

        }else{
            //Clear the cart and add the one product
            Cart::destroy();
            Cart::add('product', 'Description', 1, 69.95);
            //Pass to the processor for order processing
            return $this->process();
        }
```